# Simple questiona about JQuery Mobile Structure

Tags: mysql, jquery-mobile

I am struggling with my JQuery application. I have few script that I put them all together in one js file and then links on the pages that will be loaded.
My question is? Do I have to use the structure below in every single HTML page?

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>          
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Most of my scripts, inside of my index.js, starts with :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", '#Page', function(){

});
```

The problem is, when I start the application, they all work, but as soon as I start repeating the modules, some of them stop working.
Does anyone know what may going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by repeating `modules`? Are there any specific errors visible on the browser console?

Comment: Let me to explain better. When I open one of the pages, it populates automatically a select input, the user select one item and press a button that post the information to the database, then I can repeat the action, selecting another item and doing the same. From certain point, after some repetition, the select input, stops being populated, I have to go to the previous page and then go back, so it will be populated again.